# Give example of two subrings of R such that their set product and sum is not a subring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $ R$ be a ring. Let $S $ and $T $ be two subrings of $R$ . Define $$S+T=\{  s+t : s \in S, t \in T        \}$$

$$S.T=\{s.t: s\in S, t\in T\}$$

I took $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}[x]$ as example but was not able to contruct anything.

Edit:

Ring does not need  to have identity element. I am following Gallian approach. I have read that in Artin's book, author assumes that ring need to have identity.

Edit 2: Is there a reason I am not able to construct example in  $\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}[x]$ 
 or it is just my mathematicial imaturity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do your rings require identity? Do subrings need to share identity with containing rings?  These are issues that frequently come up when people ask this sort of question.

Comment: I have edited the post. Regarding that finite sum thing, I have removed it as I was confused earlier with some notation. Please have a look. @rscbwieb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ of polynomials in two variables. Then $S:=\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $T:=\mathbb{Z}[y]$ are subrings such that their sum and product (pairwise defined as you did) are not subrings, as the elements $(x+y)(x+y)=x^2+2xy+y^2\not\in S+T$ and $x^2y+xy^2\not\in ST$ show.

---

**EDITED IN RESPONSE TO EDITION OF THE OP:**

1) In $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ we can give the following example:
$S:=\mathbb{Z}[x^2]$, $T:=\mathbb{Z}[x^3]$. Then $(x^2+x^3)^2\not\in S+T$, $x^4x^3+x^2x^6=x^7+x^8\not\in ST$.

2) In $\mathbb{Z}$ this cannot happen: every subring is an ideal, so $S:=n\mathbb{Z}$, $T:=m\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}$, and then $S+T=\gcd(n,m)\mathbb{Z}$ (by Bézout's identity) and $ST=nm\mathbb{Z}^2=nm\mathbb{Z}$, which are again subrings.

Comment: If you use the identity element, then you can find simpler elements disproving $S+T, ST$ as rings, but I have chosen those so that you can construct an analogous example for a ring without identity

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to find counterexamples in $Z$ and $Z[x]$

Comment: @StammeringMathematician Please, see the edit to my answer

Comment: So being an ideal is a strong condition then.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician Well, it is not because of ideals, but because of the "small" or "rigid" that the structure of $\mathbb{Z}$ is: every ideal is principal, and $\mathbb{Z}^2=\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, about edit 2:

**Note** Let $R$ be a subring of $\mathbb Z$. Then since $(R,+)$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb Z,+)$ you get that $R=n \mathbb Z$ for some $n$.

It is easy to see that 
$$(n\mathbb Z) +(m \mathbb Z)=\mbox{gcd}(m,n) \mathbb Z \\
(m\mathbb Z) (n\mathbb Z) =(mn) \mathbb Z$$

That's why such example cannot exist in $\mathbb Z$. The reason why this proof holds is because the additive group of the ring is cylcic.